# How to process every date key-value pair inside this dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have this array of dictionaries in python.

```
array_dict  = [
                    {'Name': 'John', 'Date': '2/18/1998', 'Pay': 21.63},
                    {'Name': 'John', 'Date': '7/7/1999', 'Pay': 15.87}
              ]
```

I want to convert every date key-pair inside the dictionary to look like this;

```
out_dict = [
                {'Name': 'John', 'Date': '18-02-1998', 'Pay': 21.63},
                {'Name': 'John', 'Date': '07-07-1999', 'Pay': 15.87}
           ]
```

I know how to do the date conversion. The code for doing the conversion is like this;

```
datetime.strptime(date_str, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

where `date_str` contains the date string such as `'2/18/1998'`.

How do I apply this conversion code across all the pairs inside the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dict.update`

**Ex:**

```
import pprint
from datetime import datetime
array_dict  = [
                    {'Name': 'John', 'Date': '2/18/1998', 'Pay': 21.63},
                    {'Name': 'John', 'Date': '7/7/1999', 'Pay': 15.87}
              ]

for i in array_dict:
    i.update({"Date": datetime.strptime(i["Date"], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d-%m-%Y") })
pprint.pprint(array_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Date': '18-02-1998', 'Name': 'John', 'Pay': 21.63},
 {'Date': '07-07-1999', 'Name': 'John', 'Pay': 15.87}]
```

Comment: I notice you use pprint. This is new to me. Is it good practice to replace print with pprint all the time? Seems pprint is superior. Are there situations when print is still better than pprint?

Answer (score 1):

If there are really only those three keys, you can use a list comprehension:

```
out_dict = [
    {
        'Name': d['Name'],
        'Pay': d['Pay'],
        'Date': datetime.strptime(d['Date'], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d-%m-%Y"),
    } for d in array_dict
]
```

Otherwise, I'd copy it over and modify it in a loop:

```
out_dict = []
for d in array_dict:
    out_dict.append(dict(d))  # make a copy
    out_dict[-1]['Date'] = datetime.strptime(d['Date'], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```